# Variable Not initialized even though it is getting initialized in the loop

Tags: java

I am getting a problem in running this code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class divisi {

    public int findGCD(int a, int b) {
        int c, d;
        int div;
        if(a>b) {
            c = a;
        } else {
            c = b;
        }

        for(d = 1 ; d <= c; d++) {
           if(a%d == 0 && b%d == 0) {
               div = d;
           }
        }
        return div;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter two numbers:");
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int b1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


        divisi obj2 = new divisi();
        int m = obj2.findGCD(a1 , b1);
        System.out.println("The GCD or HCF of the entered numbers is " + m);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error that variable div is not initialized, even though in the for loop it is getting initialized (div = d). Can someone tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: That line is not guaranteed to execute.

Comment: And the compiler is not that smart about detecting initialization anyway. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html

Comment: But...it is getting initialized within a **if** statement. What if that **if** statement's condition fails? Then it won't be initialized, do: `int div = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `a <= 0` and `b <=0` you will never initialize `div`.

Just fix it by initializing `div` by `0`.